# boundary value of single complex variable holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, boundary-value-problem

Is it right that there exists (one variable) holomorphic functions on the open unit disk, that are zero on the unit circle. If this is true, in what sense can we define this boundary value on the circle. Because, radial convergence would imply global nullity of the function.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  A function holomorphic on the unit disk and continuous on the closure, with value identically zero on the unit circle?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @seth sure it would not be continuous, but I am trying to define some boundary value in a some sense to be defined